# Are there any other job options for goblins?

Tags: harry-potter, gringotts

I am a goblin in the wizarding world, and I just lost my job at Gringotts(FYI, I was NOT fired, I quit first) and I would really like to know if there are any job opportunities that don't discriminate towards goblins.  I need a job soon so would you please help?

Comment: Everyone has a career choice, goblins are known to excel in certain areas, so you seem them fill those roles. It's kind of like asking if men are allowed to be a "nanny".

Comment: Goblins don't like to mix with wizards.  They probably have Healers and professors, but these heal and teach goblins only, so we don't meet them.

Comment: There seems to be a long history of goblins making weaponry and being blacksmiths, but it’s not clear how much that happens in modern times. I think they mint the coins for Gringotts as well.

Comment: You quit a job allowing you to count money all day? You're SURE you're a goblin? Like, you've been tested, right?

Comment: I would rather open a competitor bank..

Comment: We aren't completely sure about the identity of my dad.  But they were about to fire me, and quitting looks better on my resume.

Comment: As a goblin, you should know better than us, as we've mostly been informed about the wizard view of the world, via the works of J K Rowling, and wizards mostly ignore goblins except where such matters as their control of Gringotts forces them to deal with them.

Comment: Well, they DID say that the questions on this site should be practical and help you solve real problems! I'm flagging to migrate to workplace.SE :)

Comment: @SJuan76 True, but how to get from roundworld to discworld?

Answer (score 13):

As @alexwlchan mentioned in his comment, Goblins are renowned primarily for their management of Gringotts as well as their metalsmithing and weapons manufactury (the Sword of Gryffindor being a particularly fine example).

> ‘Well, goblins won’t share any of their magic, either,’ said Ron. ‘You
>   won’t tell us how to make swords and armour the way you do. **Goblins
>   know how to work metal in a way wizards have never –’**

They're also known, canonically to mint the wizarding coinage

> On real Galleons that’s just a serial number **referring to the goblin
>   who cast the coin.** On these fake coins, though, the numbers will
>   change to reflect the time and date of the next meeting.

Other known professions for goblins, however include;

- [Commerce/Sales of precious metals](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ug_the_Unreliable)
- [Manufacturing of scents](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Alguff_the_Awful)
- [Newspaper Editorialist](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ragnok_the_Pigeon-Toed)
- [Philosophy](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_goblin_philosopher)
- [Collections](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ludovic_Bagman%27s_goblin_creditors)
- [Public Relations](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Eargit_the_Ugly)
- [Lift Operator](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Red)
- [Smokey-voiced jazz singer](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Goblin_jazz_singer)
- [Legitimate businessman](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gnarlak)

Please note that a number of these feature only in the *additional* Harry Potter source materials such as the computer games, Wizard cards and film props.

Comment: Lets not forget professional gambler, as seen in the Bagman caper

Answer (score 5):

This is partly due to the fact that JKR heavily drew on the existing mythology.

Goblins have always been treasure hoarders and often artisans.

And she kind of lumped in the (missing from Potterverse) niche of dwarves with their mining, smithing, artifact making and also gold hoarding.

The point you made about needing a wand for other professions is plausible but not 100% canon supported - e.g. house-elves can do magic without wands.

I'm not aware of many Goblins in other trades (there was an unidentified philosopher goblin mentioned on Wikia though).

Comment: Dwarves do exist in the Potterverse, because Gilderoy Lockheart hired them to impersonate Cupid for Valentines Day. http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dwarf

Comment: @pleurocoelus These dwarves are less like classic dwarves and more like gnomes. And yes I know that there are Harry Potter gnomes.

Answer (score 2):

Goblins are also known to be involved in the gambling trade (Goblet of Fire). I would suggest setting yourself up as a bookmaker.

I would not use Ludo Bagman to set your odds (https://www.pottermore.com/quidditch-world-cup/daily-prophet-reports-2014) as he will leave you open to arbetrage on the simplest of bets.

Comment: Although he bet money with Goblins, there's no indication that they were professional gamblers, any more than Bagman himself.

Comment: FYI, the link you've posted is behind a password wall.

Comment: Pottermore have now made the link public - it's halfway down the article search for Bagman